# TYPO3: Translated mm records in command controller

Tags: typo3, command-line-interface, extbase

I am trying to get the translated records from the command controller by calling a function from extension repository like this.

```
function findAllForLang($lang){
    //$lang = 1;
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(false);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setLanguageMode(false);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setLanguageUid($lang);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setLanguageOverlayMode('hideNonTranslated');

     $query->matching(
       $query->logicalAnd(
           $query->equals('sys_language_uid', $lang),
           //$query->equals('mmfield.sys_language_uid', $lang)
        )
     );
    return $query->execute();
```

I am getting the translated records. But the mm inline records are not translated and getting the default language records.
Is there any specific way to get all the translated inline records ?
TYPO3 version is 8.7.20
Thank you

Comment: TYPO3 version, please. That's pretty (immensely) important when trying to answer language-related questions ;)

Comment: TYPO3 version is 8.7.20

Answer (score 0):

There is a longstanding bug regarding fetching of translated relations with Extbase: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

It was fixed for TYPO3 v9+.

For your case I suggest to build the query yourself with the (newer) doctrine-dbal API:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html

Comment: OK thank you. Then no solution for this typo3 version.
I am doing the same way already.

Comment: From your code example it looks like the Extbase query builder. I suggest the doctrine-dbal query builder.